# Adding or removing words from tridion spell checker

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions, content-manager

What is the right way to add / remove words from Tridion spell checker (company name, terms etc.)? Looking at the default configuration, it looks like we can add a new configuration element to your language (\WebUI\Models\CME\SpellChecker\SpellCfg.xml).

```
<language name="English (United States)" id="am">
<options/>
<mainLex>
<path>D:\opt\apps\tridion\web\WebUI\Models\CME\SpellChecker\runtime\lex\</path>
<files>
<file>myssceam.tlx</file>
<file>myssceam2.clx</file>
</files>
</mainLex>
<customLex/>
</language>
```

You can then edit "myssceam.tlx" with your new suggestions / replacements. Is this the only way to customize this behavior? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [online documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-AE4A70CC-5099-47D5-867B-3C777C9A0DC7):

To add a custom dictionary, create a plain-text file listing supplementary dictionary entries, save it to the Content Manager server, and configure it in the SpellChecker configuration file, **SpellCfg.xml**.

**Procedure**

1. To specify additional words to add to one of the SpellChecker dictionaries, create a plain-text file containing one word on each line, and ending in an empty line.
2. Save this file to a location on your Content Manager server machine.
3. Open the file

   ```
   %TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Models\CME\SpellChecker\SpellCfg.xml
   ```

   for editing.
4. Find the language element with the id and name attributes set to the language for which you created the file.
5. Inside this element, inside its `customLex` element, create a `<path>` subelement followed by a `<files>` subelement, and create one `<file>` subelement inside `<files>`.
6. Set the value of `<path>` to the full path to the new file.
7. Set the value of `<file>` to the name of the new file.
8. Verify that your `<customLex>` section looks as follows:

   ```
   <customLex>
       <path>d:\projects\spellchecker\languages\Italian</path>
       <files>
           <file>Myitdict.txt</file>
       </files>
   </customLex>
   ```

   where *d:\projects\spellchecker\languages\Italian* is the path to your file, and *Myitdict.txt* is the name of your file.
9. Save and close SpellCfg.xml.
10. Restart IIS to apply your changes.